# How to run Urdu tokenizer in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

somebody help me. How to run urdu-tokenizer.py file. i have taken this file from the following link https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/cmt-40/Nice/Urdu-MT/code/urdu-tokenizer.py
Do anyone know how to add urdu text file to run urdu-tokenizer.py file.

Answer (score 0):

From the file:

```
def printUsage():
     print "Usage : %s input.txt > output.txt" % sys.argv[0]`.
```

So you run it from command line, like this:

```
python urdu-tokenizer.py input_in_urdu.txt > output.txt
```

Then you examine `output.txt`.

Comment: "input_in_urdu.txt" do this file need path or i should write the file name directly?

Comment: If the file is in the same directory where you write the command, you don't need any extra path. Same as with any other command-line tool, like `cat`.

Comment: Do you know that truecaser for Urdu exist or not?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I don't even know if a uniform or reversible case transform exists for Urdu. (For some other languages, it definitely does not.)

Comment: Thank you for your help.